# Intellij Scala- unable to find Scala App

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I just set up Scala in Intellij(along with SDK and JDK)

File -> Project -> Scala -> Scala

Created a project.

under project name src --> right click --> I can see 1.Scala Class , 2.Scala Worksheet , 3.Scala Script , But the Scala application or App option is not coming .

what am i doing wrong here. Please help

Comment: Btw  I choose Scala class --> from drop down selected Object and created an object 
=========
object test {
println("Hi ")
}
==========
unable to run the program -> Run option is not enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in Java you should create a class, that has main method, that can be found by java machine and get run. The searched method has signature

In java:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  //your code goes here
}
```

In scala:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  //your code goes here
}
```

Also in scala you can extend from App(scala.App, all names from package scala._ are imported by default):

```
object Main extends App{
  //your code goes here
}
```

That moves your code into automatically created function def main(args: Array[String]): Unit. This option is "faster", but limited in some functionality.

So, click "Scala class", pick object, add "extends App" clause or write "def main ..."

Comment: Hi Friend,Thank you very much :) - I clearly missed the main method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a main method in some object to make it "runnable":

```
object test extends App { 
  println("Hi");
}
```

or

```
object test { 
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = println("Hi");
}
```

Extending `App` creates a `main` method under the hood for you, but messes with initialization.